# Can't find a formula for P(B)

Tags: probability

I just started learning probability:

$C=$ A person carries a disease

$B=$ A person tests positive

$$P(C)=0.04$$
$$P(B\mid C)=0.9$$
What is $P(B\cap C)$ and $P(B)$?

Using the formula $P(B\mid C)=\cfrac{P(B\cap C)}{P(C)}$, I can easily find $P(B\cap C)$. I can't seem to find a formula to find $P(B)$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean D??

Comment: My bad, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

$P(B)=P(C)P(B|C)+P(C')P(B|C')$.
$P(B|C)=$People who test positive and have the disease.
$P(B|C')=$People who test positive and don't have the disease.
Consider drawing yourself a tree diagram too.

Comment: I though about this formula, but I don't know $P(B/C')$. If a person doesn't have a disease, can't we say that the probability of testing positive is 0?

Comment: Medical testing isn't always accurate there is always the chance of a false positive.

Comment: P(B|C)=0.9 this means that given the person carries the disease, there is a 90% chance that their test comes back positive. That also means that there is a 10% chance that a person who has the disease is given a negative test result.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting $P(B/C')$ from $P(B'/C)$.

Comment: @user3552680 $P(B | C)=0.9$ doesn't imply $P(B' | C')=0.9$

Answer (score 0):

In order to find $P(B)$ you need to know $$P(B\mid C')$$ as well, that is the probability that a person tests positive *given* that they do not carry the disease. Unfortunately, this conditional probability $P(B\mid C')$ is not something you can calculate yourself. It will be given in the question.

***If*** you knew the value of $P(B\mid C')$ then $P(B)=P(C)\times P(B\mid C) + P(C')\times P(B\mid C')=0.04\times0.9+0.96\times P(B\mid C')$. But we don't know what $P(B\mid C')$ is equal to.

Answer (score 0):

This question has no answer, as $P(B\mid C')$ can be anything and the two given conditions will still hold. (Draw a tree diagram to verify that $P(B\mid C')$ can indeed be any number between 0 and 1.)
And we need to know $P(B\mid C')$ in order to calculate $$P(B)=P(C)P(B\mid C)+P(C')P(B\mid C').$$